# mojoPortal OR Umbraco?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, mojoportal

I have been look around for Free/Open Source ASP.NET CMS / Portal systems for a while now, and have seived it down to two different ones.

Umbraco - http://umbraco.org

mojoPortal - http://www.mojoportal.com

Both look excellent and have different appealing features, but I am looking for people who have used both and which one you went with and why??

Comment: I have moved to Umbraco and found it hands down better than mojoPortal - Anyone thinking the same, I would highly recommend Umbraco

Comment: I found  http://nishantwork.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/useful-resources-for-umbraco-cms-development/   this one here is a lot of link for Umbraco develoment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I actually went for Umbraco in the end and would never look back, its incredibly easy to install and use

To install you can use the web platform installer to install it and the AMAZING amount of free projects you can EASILY install with a couple of clicks make it by far the best CMS out there

http://our.umbraco.org/projects

If you are unsure where to start have a read of this

http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/post/A-Complete-Newbies-Guide-To-Umbraco-CMS.aspx

Comment: @leen30 , Does it support rtl langs? Thank you

Answer (score 9):

I tried Umbraco and it is not for the timid.  I feel I'm a fairly technical person, Sr. Web Developer... and after several hours I gave up.

MojoPortal just works.

It has its flaws, but the simple fact that it just works means it wins.

Comment: This is true, but once you understand what they are trying to do, you understand the complexity. Basically the high customization ability comes at the cost of the initial learning curve.

Answer (score 8):

I used Kentico, DNN, Sitecore, Joomla, CMS Made Simple (Yes admittedly not mojoPortal). Umbraco is by far the most powerful if you are after a highly customised and highly specified solution. Linq2Umbraco just seals the deal.

However, if you are after idiot proof CMS with everything built in, and your biggest concern is to look for check boxes to enable forum/blogs/whatever other joke modules/bells and whistles/etc. Umbraco isn't for you. IMO Kentico/DNN are the ones.

Edit - And 3 years later, I've used SharePoint, epiServer, SiteFinity as well.

Umbraco still wins hands down.

Comment: @user404888: I voted you down for the downright unfriendly language in your response.  If you edit and remove nasty tone, I would undo my down vote - as you do provide some useful information.

Answer (score 4):

mojoPortal seems easier to use to me and it works even with javascript disabled like using noscript browser plugin. Seems more care of accessibility has been taken using progressive enhancement javascript techniques whereas you can't manage your site at all with javascript disabled using Umbraco.

Comment: Honestly, who has javascript disabled these days?  Even mobile devices are starting to support js.

Comment: If your customers are IT professionals who visit your site while remoted to a server, you may want to consider how your site renders in a secured browser.  As you may have guessed, that's my customer base.

Comment: @stimms: Screen Readers, blind people... google... (although they try to follow js links when they can)

Comment: cmon now, without JS support we are back in 1999 again.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried mojoPortal, but I love Umbraco.

Things I like:

- Clean code
- Uses XSLT, python, or .NET to extend
- Awesome community support
- Tutorial videos for easy learning
- Admin area is extensible
- Good plug-in projects

But really its because I can use it for both small and large projects easily.

Comment: I would hay mojoPortal also have good videos. http://www.mojoportal.com/developertrainingvideos.aspx

Comment: You have to pay to watch the Umbraco videos. My experience of Umbracos documentation is pretty bad, unless you pay money.

Comment: The new documentation section on Our Umbraco has gotten much better in the last year IMO - http://our.umbraco.org/documentation