# Which CMS is easy to use DotNetNuke or Umbraco. Further can we integrate our existing project with it?

Tags: .net, asp.net, dotnetnuke, umbraco

We are in the process of implementing a CMS for our project which currently extensively uses asp.net master pages and css. Also the application is data-driven and controls like gridview and listview are used. After a little search we zeroed on two CMS dotnetnuke and umbraco. Now my question is:

1. Which one of the two CMS is best suited and easy to use?
2. Do they support integration of existing code and UI's

Please provide links for further reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179563/umbraco-is-it-just-me-or-is-it-really-hard-to-use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the integration goes its very complicated to integrate an existing application with it CMS, especially if it is dynamic and uses controls like gridview etc. Here I share link for:

1. [Problems in integration of existing application with dotnetnuke](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/41.aspx)
2. [When to use dotnetnuke](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2005/02/04/367458.aspx)
3. [Dotnetnuke vs Umbraco](http://seablick.com/blog/157/paul-sterling-on-umbraco-vs-dnn.aspx)

Further I quote the following comparisons between the two:

> Both have the advantage of being open source programs, which means they are constantly updated and improved. There are many plugins and applications created by a core of invested users, increasing functionality and removing bugs with regularity.
>
> Still, there are plenty of differences, as anyone who has used both systems will note.
>
> Here are some things to consider about Umbraco:
>
> - It can be edited in Microsoft Word, making for easy editing for most users.
> - There are OSS or commercial install options
> - A high-quality, highly functional CMS
> - Install gives you a blank page – no template, not much of anything else – This means plenty of freedom and flexibility – freedom to succeed or freedom to fail. Success of a site is entirely up to a developer, meaning you must have a highly qualified and creative developer who also knows legal compliance and standards compliance.
> - Umbraco has high requirements for hosting, so it is difficult to find a “shared” hosting environment that will support it
> - Still working on good ecommerce solutions
> - Version 4 has better support for Safari and Firefox
> - There are good plugins available, and a management system built into Umbraco
>
> By contrast, here are some items to consider about DotNetNuke:
>
> Has a proprietary feel, despite being open source
>
> - Dot NET developers like it, those who are not dot NET developers have trouble with it
> - Based on Microsoft’s ASP.NET, which is the most popular web technology currently
> - Cheap to use and reduces total development costs – no ongoing licensing fees
> - Full access to source code so it can be altered to fit individual organizations
> - Can manage text, image, documents, links, events, news, banner ads and threaded info
> - Supports multiple websites
> - Installs easily
> - Can manage site hosting, content, security, web design and membership in one program
> - Multi-language ability
> - Fully extensible and scalable
> - User friendly interface and intuitve site wizards, help icons and interface for those familiar with Dot NET

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its worth noting the pub date on the second link you posted "When to use DotNetNuke" is 2005, which is, not to be impolite, ridiculously old in web-years and I can't imagine it being relevant at all.

Comment: @Ian please share any latest link you have

Answer (score 4):

I have been using Umbraco for the past 2 months and about to invest to being certified.

What I like about Umbraco is that you can go easy or very difficult. What I mean is out of the box you can build something very quickly and be up and running soon, then build upon it.

I installed dotnetnuke before but found it quite sluggish but I may be wrong.

The concepts are easy to pick up. If you know XSLT, asp.net MasterTemplates then you're well on your way to developing a simple site. If you know UserControls you can really excel with extra functionality.

Pretty much all the code you put into Umbraco is what's generated.

I've successfully converted an existing ASP.net site over.

I agree with the hosting, you will need a single domain, Umbraco doesn't work from a subdirectory. What you do need is a simple reseller pack. Development environment is very easy to setup with Cassinni.

What is your existing site developed in?

Comment: my current site is in asp.net.

Comment: sorry I should have read your initial posting a bit better!

It should be very quick to convert the site over.

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco has its BASE interface which is REST based. If you need to pull the data out and use it else where (ie in your existing application) then you can.

http://umbraco.org/documentation/books/introduction-to-base

Comment: What makes you say its not secure? BASE can be secured using Umbraco's built in membership functionality if required but I fail to see that mentioned in the question? Also you've littered this question with links to the same differing question which barely mentions Umbraco, why?

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco is very easy working with, and I would certainly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using DotNetNuke for about 5 years and its been great to work with.
Its its a bit abstracted from what most .NET developers are used too, so working with it will take some getting used too. I found it pretty easy to make the transition my self.
There are some great books out there regarding DotNetNuke development as well as some great resources on line.

As far as working with existing code bases I I have to agree with @Coder. What ever you use this will be a time consuming process.

Comment: Is dotnetnuke now in a stable version ? Or still it has some loopholes to overcome >